# hp envy 4 - dual win 8 with ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, 13.04, dual-boot, hp

I have win8 on my envy 4 ullttrabook and i want to dual win8 with ubuntU.
I download the instulation and run it throw usb.
But, the installision does not recognize my hard disc ,while im in it, throw the usb.
Whay should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you that I don't trust HP and I think of Windows 8 is difficult and unnecessary. Do you need anything from Microsoft? So we are slaves of these companies: the latter & Apple.
I cannot supply any solution with W8 but a good idea could be to burn an image on a dvd. So did I on my computer Dell W7. Therefore both two operating systems run well.